# CodeIgniter Form Validaton + JS. Form re-population

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a from with a checkbox, and depending on the checkbox state 2 different divs are shown.

```
            var alias = document.getElementById('alias');
            var list = document.getElementById('list');
            if(document.getElementById('isList').checked)
            {
                alias.style.display = 'none';
                list.style.display = 'table-row';

            } else {
                alias.style.display = 'table-row';
                list.style.display = 'none';
            }
```

Here is the `HTML/PHP` (relevant) part:

```
<tr id="alias" style="display:table-row;">
      <td>' . form_label('Destination:', 'destination') . '</td>
      <td>' . form_textarea('destination') . '</td>
</tr>
<tr  id="list" style="display:none;">
     <td>' . form_label('File Path:', 'list_path') . '</td>
     <td>' . form_input('list_path') . '</td>
</tr>
```

`alias` div is shown by default on page load, `list` shown then i click on `isList` checkbox, and `alias` is shown again when i click on the checkbox again. 
This part works great and pretty straight froward.

Now, I add CodeIgniter Form Validation plugin, set appropriate rules and set-up validation plugin to re-populate the form with.

Without checkbox enabled everything works great. On errors form is re-populated.

However, when form is submitted with checkbox enabled, I have an issue. 
CI's Form Validation plugin re-populates the form, **and re-enables the checkbox**,
but the `list` div that is supposed to be shown when checkbox enabled is not there,
and instead the `alias` div is shown.

Is there any way around this issue? Can i have the `list` div shown on `list` validation error?

Also, i would like to avoid using `JavaScript` form validation, and stick with my good old `PHP`.

Thank you in advance.
-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha... I just fixed it with a simple

`<body onload="showHide();">`